# SET PATH in batch file

Tags: php, batch-file

I am still getting this error.

>
'php' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

This is how i set the path in my batch file

```
SET PATH = %PATH%;"C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\php.exe"
```

Comment: [Check this](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm).

Comment: Hi,I just want to set in my batch file,i dont want to set in windows environment variables

Comment: And the program name. `SET PATH = %PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12`

Comment: Plus we normally use the path command not the set command although both work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.5.12\
```

You add directory path to the `%PATH%`, not file path.

Do consider what context you are calling this.

You cannot have a batch file that you load from file Explorer and expect the Environment to be global.

The `%PATH%` is only updated in the command prompt instance running the batch script.

Comment: Hi,Thank you it solves.I also tried your solution before i post here,but the problem is i put extra space in between of PATH=PATH=%PATH%. as you noticed my code the i posted above which has spaces.Thank you works like a charm